# CKeditor Html 5 <figure> tag issue

Tags: ckeditor

I using CKeditor version 4. And I facing issue related HTML 5 tag.
Input Html Code:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
    <div class="item-cont"> 
        <a href="contents/view/home">
          <figure>
            <img src="img/1468996695_img-1.jpg" />
          </figure>
          <div class="item-content">
            <div class="align-content">
              <div class="text-cont">
                <h1>Text</h1>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Output return from Ckeditor

```
 <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
    <div class="item-cont">
    <p><a href="contents/view/home"><img src="img/gallery/subGallery_1/1468996695_img-1.jpg" /> </a></p>

  <div class="item-content">
     <div class="align-content">
       <div class="text-cont">
       <h1><a href="contents/view/home">Aarhus</a></h1>

          <p><a href="contents/view/home">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry.</a></p>
     </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Issue:-

1. It will replace the "figure" tag with "p" tag
2. Outer anchor tag replace with inner anchor tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the proper solution

Change in CKeditor Setting

```
$(function(){
     CKEDITOR.replace('tinyeditor');
     CKEDITOR.dtd.a.div = 1;
     CKEDITOR.dtd.a.figure = 1;
     CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent = true;
});
```

This can resolve the issue of anchor tag and figure tag

Comment: You can add figure and figcaption to config.extraAllowedContent without disabling the content filter completely.  Otherwise, the bit about the dtd helped me with the same problem, so thank you.