# Produce HTML5 Output from CKEditor

Tags: jsf, primefaces, ckeditor4.x, primefaces-extensions

I am using CKEditor 4.9.1 in my project. I want that CKEditor will produce HTML5 formatted output in place of HTML. Right now it is producing Font Tag and in table it is given the width and other attributes which is not supposed to be come in HTML5 output.Please help me out to find the solution for the same.

Comment: Looks like you have to tweak CKEditor config found these posts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26279189/ckeditor-changing-all-my-html . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41496028/how-to-use-br-instead-of-br-in-ckeditor . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888373/ckeditor-html-5-figure-tag-issue

Comment: @Melloware: Then mark one as a duplicate or is none of them a fit?

Comment: I don't think any of them are quite duplicate but they are all suggestions from different people who have had HTML5 issues with CKEDITOR and some different ways to  solve each type of problem.